# Cant get references to work with typescript

Tags: typescript

AppViewModel.ts

```
interface IAppViewModel
{
    status: any;
}
export class AppViewModel{
....
}
```

IdentityViewModel.ts

```
///<reference path="AppViewModel.ts" />

export class IdentityViewModel {

    constructor(parent : IAppViewModel) {
    }
}
```

Should i not be able to tell that parent implements IAppViewModel in identityViewModel? It tells me that it do not exist in the current scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a top-level `export` directive, you shouldn't be using `<reference...` to link the files together. IdentityViewModel.ts should instead `import appvm = module('./AppViewModel');`. You'll also need to `export` any interface you expect to be visible outside the originating file.